# How to passs currency in BargainFinderMaxRQ request?

Tags: sabre

i want response bases on passed currency code in request of **BargainFinderMaxRQ**
but i can not get any request parameter where i pass currency code please help

response : here i get currency bases on destination country
  "AirItineraryPricingInfo": {
                "PricingSource": "ADVJR1",
                "PricingSubSource": "MIP",
                "FareReturned": "true",
                "ItinTotalFare": {
                    "BaseFare": {
                        "Amount": "15030",
                        "CurrencyCode": "INR",
                        "DecimalPlaces": "0"
                    },
                    "FareConstruction": {
                        "Amount": "208.78",
                        "CurrencyCode": "NUC",
                        "DecimalPlaces": "2"
                    },
                    "EquivFare": {
                        "Amount": "80.000",
                        "CurrencyCode": "BHD",
                        "DecimalPlaces": "3"
                    },
                    "Taxes": {
                        "Tax": {
                            "TaxCode": "TOTALTAX",
                            "Amount": "28.200",
                            "CurrencyCode": "BHD",
                            "DecimalPlaces": "3"
                        }
                    },
                    "TotalFare": {
                        **"Amount": "108.200",**
                        **"CurrencyCode": "BHD",**
                        "DecimalPlaces": "3"
                    }
                },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request this under PriceRequestInformation/CurrencyCode.